# Remove vertical line in table with fixed column using element ui

Tags: typescript, vue.js, element-ui

#ask

i using element-ui. [visit](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table)

and using fixed column in table data.

[image: table]

and will remove vertical line in above image after scroll horizontal in table with fixed column on element ui. but how to resolve this because that shadow not detect in inspect element?

thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below CSS may help you.

```
.el-table__fixed, .el-table__fixed-right {
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

**but how to resolve this because that shadow not detect in inspect element?**

it has created extra div outside of table as you can see in below image.

[image]